# How to find a marked item out of $K < N$ marked items when K is unknown?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, grovers-algorithm, complexity-theory

I'm wondering about time complexities of variants of the searching problem in Grover's Algorithm. I know that using G.A. the time complexity required to find a market item reduces to $O(\sqrt N)$.

**How about the following scenario:**

You are given access to an oracle with $K$ marked items, and $K$ is unknown. What would be a lower bound for finding a marked item using $O(\sqrt {N/K})$, with probability more than $\frac{1}{2}$?

If so, is there an algorithm to show it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_counting_algorithm